# Google Sheets: QUERY to return a single column

Tags: google-sheets, indexing, google-query-language

I'm using this query to find the most popular entries in a column of my data - how do I limit the query results to just the data entries, without returning the aggregate column:

> =QUERY(G2:G14,"select G, count(G) where G is not null group by G order by count(G) DESC label G 'Product'",-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(G2:G14,
 "select G, count(G) 
  where G is not null
  group by G
  order by count(G) desc 
  label G 'Product'", -1),, 1)
```